# Tensorflow: TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'generator'

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow

I'm just a beginner of ML-learner using Tensorflow, and on tutorials I'd like to solve "Iris" judging program without using batch solution.
Here's my code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn import datasets

sess = tf.Session()

iris = datasets.load_iris()
binary_target = np.array([1. if x==0 else 0. for x in iris.target])
iris_2d = np.array([[x[2], x[3]] for x in iris.data])

x1_data = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32, shape=[1])
x2_data = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32, shape=[1])
y_ = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32, shape=[1])
w1 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal(shape=[1]))
w2 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal(shape=[1]))
b  = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal(shape=[1]))

x1w1 = tf.multiply(x1_data, w1)
x2w2 = tf.multiply(x2_data, w2)
xsum = tf.add(x1w1, x2w2)
output = tf.add(xsum, b)
loss   = tf.square(tf.subtract(y_, output))

my_opt = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.02)
train_step = my_opt.minimize(loss)

init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
sess.run(init)

for i in range(1000):
    rand_index = np.random.choice(len(iris_2d),1)
    rand_x  = iris_2d[rand_index]
    rand_x1 = np.array([[x][0][0] for x in rand_x])
    rand_x2 = np.array([[x][0][1] for x in rand_x])
    rand_y  = np.array([[y]] for y in binary_target[rand_index])
    sess.run(train_step, feed_dict={x1_data: rand_x1, x2_data: rand_x2, y_: rand_y})
    if (i+1)%100 == 0:
        print('Step #' + str(i+1) + ' w1 = ' + str(sess.run(w1)) + ' w2 = ' + str(sess.run(w2)) + \
              ' b = ' + str(sess.run(b)))
```

And always I got this message:

```
"C:\Users\Naoki Nakamura\PycharmProjects\tensorflow\venv\Scripts\python.exe" "C:/Users/Naoki Nakamura/PycharmProjects/tensorflow/venv/naoki/iris.py"
2017-12-13 16:07:00.955740: I C:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\rel-win\M\windows\PY\36\tensorflow\core\platform\cpu_feature_guard.cc:137] Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: AVX AVX2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Naoki Nakamura/PycharmProjects/tensorflow/venv/naoki/iris.py", line 37, in <module>
    sess.run(train_step, feed_dict={x1_data: rand_x1, x2_data: rand_x2, y_: rand_y})
  File "C:\Users\Naoki Nakamura\PycharmProjects\tensorflow\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 889, in run
    run_metadata_ptr)
  File "C:\Users\Naoki Nakamura\PycharmProjects\tensorflow\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1089, in _run
    np_val = np.asarray(subfeed_val, dtype=subfeed_dtype)
  File "C:\Users\Naoki Nakamura\PycharmProjects\tensorflow\venv\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\numeric.py", line 531, in asarray
    return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order)
TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'generator'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I think my code's wrong, but I can't figure out what's wrong...
Any help is really appreciated.
(I'm sorry about my poor English and Python ability.)

Comment: Actually type(train_step) is <class 'tensorflow.python.framework.ops.Operation'> and as you see in [Operation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Operation) - _Operation can be executed by passing it to tf.Session.run_

Answer (score 1):

In rand_y [without square brackets you've got generator](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0289/).

Change your rand_y as:

```
rand_y  = np.array([y for y in binary_target[rand_index]])
```

Output:

```
Step #100 w1 = [-0.9143346] w2 = [ 1.27399015] b = [ 2.25566769]
Step #200 w1 = [-0.80373073] w2 = [ 1.27550149] b = [ 2.0513134]
...
```